# RN2483 very high TX current consumption

Tags: current-measurement, microchip, lora

I am using a Microchip RN2483 LoRa module and I observed a very high TX current consumption, >400mA, sometimes 500mA. It doesn't happen systematically but when it does, it seems to affect every subsequent transmission.

What I observed:
[image: observed LoRa transmission current consumption]

What a normal transmission should look like:
[image: normal LoRa transmission current consumption]

My module is configured to transmit in SF12 at +14dBm, with ADR and AR off. Its firmware version is 1.0.3. Nothing in the datasheet hints that such a consumption should happen.

My measurement setup (I'm using a Joulescope) doesn't seem to be at fault since every other current consumption, except this LoRa TX, is consistent with what is expected.

Any ideas ?

Comment: How about a schematic and links to the data sheets?

Comment: I don't have any schematic since my device is manufactured by a third party. You can find the datasheet here: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/RN2483